# Missing "Server view" in Eclipse / IBM RSA Rational Software Architect

Tags: eclipse, rational-rsa, ibm-rational

I'm missing the *"Server view"* in my fresh RSA for WebSphere Software installation.
It's also not available in *"Window > Show View > Other..."*.

Does anybody have an idea? I expected the view to be available right from the beginning.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's the solution: You have to **enable the "JEE Developer Capability" in RSA.**

You can find all the capabilities under *"Window" - "Preferences" - "General" - "Capabilities"*. After you enabled the mentioned capability the server view will be available.

Comment: When I got to that spot above, "J2EE Developer" was unchecked and locked, but by clicking on the "Advanced..." button, I was able to check that checkbox and get the server view/tab.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall (and it may not be the case now), RSA installs just the base by default.  You have to go back into the install package and choose additional, optional function to install.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. As you see, the solution to my problem is a little different.